# Javafx FXML ComboBox value

Tags: java, combobox, null, javafx, fxml

So I have a form that I want a User to fill out

it must have the date at the top which are 3 combo boxes for Day, month and year.
then I give them a form which they can partially fill out

So lets say there are 4 rows
each row has a combo box and a field.

Now i've been testing for the past hour nearly to check if one when is null is the other? otherwise it's invalid.

I've tried combo.toString() and then testing if that was null or empty but that didn't work for some reason.

So basically if the combo box has no value, then the field can have no value too, but if one has a value then the other MUST, otherwise the form is invalid.

Please help

Comment: As an update:

I've taken the .getValue() approach of this. This does help in the fact that I can now check if the object - as getValue creates an object, is null.

However I still can't check if both are null, if anything is null if flags it

Comment: You can check if your ComboBox has null value by -> comboBox.getValue() == null , and for your TextField -> textField.getText().isEmpty();